# Двоичное дерево поиска с прошивкой

Tags: c, бинарное-дерево

В вузe дали следующее задание:

Написать программу для работы по запросам оператора с упорядоченной таблицей, реализованной в виде двоичного дерева поиска с прошивкой.

Ключ-целое число. Информация - строка произвольной длинны.

Узел дерева содержит ключ, указатели на правое и левое поддеревья, указатель на следующий узел в обратном порядке следования ключей и указатель на информационной поле.

При выполнении операция удаления и добавления, дерево должно не терять упорядоченности.

У меня возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Что такое указатель на следующий узел в обратном порядке?
   Т.е. это указатель на предыдущий узел?
2. Как мне поддерживать упорядоченность дерева при удалении и добавлении элемента?

   Насколько рациональна следующая идея: Обходить измененное дерево и из него строить новое дерево ?
3. Я правильно понимаю, что под прошивкой понимается ссылка указателей листьев на корень дерева?

Comment: 1) А вы знаете, что такое обход дерева в обратном порядке? Так вот, «следующий узел в обратном порядке» — это и есть узел, следующий за данным, при обходе в обратном порядке. Посмотрите в конспект.

Comment: 2) Алгоритм добавления узла в прошитое дерево есть, например, в TAOCP. Строить новое дерево обычно нерационально.

Comment: 3) Нет. Почитайте, [что такое прошитое дерево](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree), там объяснено. Вкратце: прошивка — это расстановка кое-где указателей на следующие/предыдущие узлы в обратном порядке.

Comment: 1)Обходится левое поддерево, правое, потом узел                                3)Как я понял для каждого обхода дерева своя прошивка. Нить должна указывать на следующий элемент при выбранном обходе? Красным цветом я обозначил нити http://prntscr.com/6yg3oc . Я правильно понял прошивку?

Comment: 1) Ну вот, теперь вы знаете ответ 3) прошивка только для обратного порядка, ЕМНИП.

Comment: И у `a` следующий в обратном порядке — `b`.

Comment: Т.е получается, что нитями я связывать должен так http://prntscr.com/6ygths ?

Comment: Вроде бы да. Но это только правая нить, ещё аналогично левая.

Comment: Подскажите, а что бы прошить дерево придется использовать рекурсию ? На русских сайтах я что-то не нашел алгоритмов =(

Comment: А у вас есть трёхтомник Кнута? Там должно быть. Раздел 2.3.1.

Comment: Если нет, очевидное решение с рекурсией, да. Обходите дерево в обратном порядке, запоминаете предыдущие два узла, расставляете ссылки, как надо.

Comment: Там же есть и добавление элемента в прошитое дерево, кстати. Алгоритм I. В моей книге (издание 1976-го года) страница 406.

Comment: А как серия его книг называется?

Comment: Эх. «[Искусство Программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)». Это вообще библия программиста.

Comment: Вам наверняка про неё рассказывали на первой же лекции.